# Django one-to-many field without reversing dependency

Tags: django

There are quite a few places to suggest using `ForeignKey` for one-to-many or many-to-one relationship, but I am struggling to understand how this will work without reversing dependency.

For example:

I have these 2 apps, 'settlements' and 'payments', ideally, settlements don't need to know about payments because payment records are created after settlements have been made, and a payment record can contain multiple settlements.

settlements model:

```
class Settlement(models.Model):
    ...
```

payments model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    settlements = models.ManyToManyField('Settlement')
    ....
```

This brings a fundamental schema caveat, that settlement can belong to multiple payments, which should not happen.

To enforce a settlement cannot belong to more than one payment record, I will have to put the payment `foreignkey` in Settlement:

settlements model:

```
class Settlement(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment')
    ...
```

payments model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    ....
```

While this enforce the schema validity, but seems the dependency has reversed, now that settlement needs to know about payment, just made these 2 apps tightly coupled. Also I need to create a settlement record with payment field being null, create the payment record, then go back to the settlement record to link up the payment record, this seems wrong.

Comment: why the second approach seems to be wrong? conceptually, in real life, you need to create your settlement instance first, then the payment and then bind them.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to conceptualize the relationship is as `belongs to` -- Settlement 1, 3, and 9 belong to Payment 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine found this project:

https://github.com/adsworth/django-onetomany

It's adding a unique together constraint in the manytomany relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Though the schema may make sense to have a foreign key on `Settlement` that links to a `Payment`, your application doesn't have to have that relation (or enforce it on the database). I will assume that `Settlement` can't be changed, and that you can only work with the `Payment` app.

Simply create your own intermediate model/table, and link *that* with payments. It'll be like having a ManyToMany relationship, but you can enforce the constraints on it.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
   # your fields go here

class Invoice(models.Model):
    settlement = models.OneToOneField('settlements.Settlement')
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment)
```

Note the `OneToOneField`. That's essentially a Foreign Key with a unique constraint. We're emulating a ManyToMany intermediate table, but restricting the `settlement` to only having a single record in the invoice table.

I should probably note that because we're creating a new table here, that future queries may be slow due to the extra join required. If you modify the `Settlement` model to include a ForeignKey, it'll perform and look better from a normalisation sense.