# How to model this kind of a relationship in django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I want to have two models:

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    # Bunch of products

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

***I don't want the product to know about receipt*** but just the receipt to know about the products. How do I build this relationship?

PS: One product can be in multiple receipts.

Comment: is there a reason why you can't have the product know about the receipt ? the straightforward way would be to have a many to many relationship

Comment: Not for any strict reason, just for good designing's sake; but I guess it cannot be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is just like you say a [manyTomanyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) is enough.

But if you need to store also the quantity of each ingredient on each receipe then do you need a [many2many with attributes relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

One2Many relationship doesn't come out the box with Django. However, I think this answer is what you're after : [Django one-to-many field without reversing dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635408/django-one-to-many-field-without-reversing-dependency)

Comment: I've changed the question, slightly. Sorry about that. Do you have any suggestions?